# Is there any way to find out if OSX mounted an extrernal drive as low speed USB?

Tags: macos, usb

It's infuriating - sometimes OSX decides to mounts external drive as low speed USB and I only find out when it tells me that the copying process will take hours.

Windows always warns if something like that happens. Can I somehow get OSX to tell me if it managed to establish proper high speed USB2 connection?

Answer (score 6):

You can see the device speed in the System Profiler.  Apple menu -> About This Mac -> More Info... -> USB -> click on your drive in the list.  In the lower pane you'll see a bunch of info about your drive, one of which will indicate the speed of the connection to the drive.

Comment: You can also run "system_profiler" on the command line or from a script.